# WSO2 IS and WSO2 EI Communication via self signed Certificate

Tags: wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 IS and WSO2 EI in our project. Is it possible to bridge communication between these two products using Self Signed Certificate or default keystores given by the products? Currently, EI is throwing certificate_unknown when it is hitting WSO2 IS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get the self signed public certificates of each product and put them in to the trust store (Usually `<HOME>/repository/resources/security`) of each other (IS public certificate to EI trust store and EI public certificate to IS trust store).

Comment: Thank you. I see there are 2 files in <HOME>/repository/resources/security with names wso2carbon.jks and client-truststore.jks and a folder tokenstore that has no files in it. Which in these is the public certificate? Please tell me which file I should pick and then its destination folder. Is trust store and tokenstore the same?

Comment: Trust store where you keep trusted 3rd party certificates and key store (wso2carbon.jks) where you keep the certificates used by the product. You can get the public certificate from the browser as well. Or use keytool command to extract it from the .jks.

Comment: I've extracted the IS's public cert and imported to EI client-truststore and vice versa. But while importing EI and IS servers are throwing "keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias <wso2carbon> already exists". So I've changed the alias name and imported them. Now when I try to hit IS SOAP service through EI proxy, IS is responding with this message "The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is ...AuthenticationAdminHttpsSoap11Endpoint and the WSA Action = urn:mediate...". Can you please help me understand the situation the servers are in? Thanks.

Comment: You have to use the same alias (wso2carbon). Before adding the certificate remove the existing one and add after. So you won't be getting any alias already exist error.